# Simple product inside configurable product

Tags: magento, product

Is it possible to get information about a simple product inside the configurable product in magento? I already access the information about the configurable product with the code below, but now, I need to get the stock qty of a simple product inside this configurable product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product);
$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();// get the product stock information

$product = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');//gets the id of the configurable product
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First load Configurable product**:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($Configproductid);
```

**Second: load all simple product by using configurable product:**

```
            $allProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->getUsedProducts(null, $product);
```

**3.Check simple product stock one by one:**

```
foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            if ($product->isSaleable()) {
    $Stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);

               var_dump($Stock )
            }
        }
```

Comment: Second step is giving me an error. It says that the getSkipSaleableCheck() method is undefined..